# Why does this PNG file look different depending on the browser?

Tags: colors, cross-browser, png

If you take screen shot this web page in different browser, you'd see that it displays slightly different in firefox. (7.01, ubuntu)

At first I thought it was because of color profile, but even if I turned on color management in firefox, the problem is still there.

Although it's not a very noticeable problem, I got a perfectionist boss who asked to  make it look exactly the same in every browser.  Does any one know what might have caused the problem?  Thanks!

[image: blue image]

A screenshot of comparison : You might still not be able to see the difference, but if you download the screen shot and use an image editor to check the color in 2 browsers, you'd see there's indeed differences.

[image: Screenshot of the colour difference]

Comment: It looks the same on my Firefox (version ∞) and Chromium (also version ∞).

Comment: @sarnold: In Chrome, for example, the blue is slightly darker.

Comment: @sarnold: Maybe I would be one of the perfectionist bosses that everyone would hate. But it's definitely noticeable to me.

Comment: @animuson I tried this also, and I agree with you: The blue is *slightly* darker in chrome.

Comment: Side-by-side on mine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EDOXN.png

Comment: I made one too: http://i.imgur.com/I1rx6.jpg

Comment: @animuson: wow. yours is _vastly_ different. I'd be upset about that too.

Comment: To the close voters: this is on-topic because it relates to web development and the tools it uses. Also, at least with the edits, it's pretty clear what the author is asking.

Comment: @ablmf: I had this problem before with a forum theme for my clan. What I ended up doing was just saving the files, opening them with Fireworks, and then re-saving them as PNG (and then compressing them). I don't really know what causes the issue, but it went away. It was something with the transparency causing it to add a sort of white tint to the entire image. What program are you using (for the images)?

Comment: This might be a lead:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1237366

Comment: I can confirm that visually it looks pretty much the same to me on a Mac with Opera, Chrome, and Firefox, but using the eyedropper tool on the Firefox rendering shows an RGB of (74, 192, 244) instead of (87, 190, 240) like the other browsers.

Comment: @animuson I'm using gimp.  I might try your solution if no direct solution appears.

Comment: People with laptops: tilt your LCDs up, and look at it from down up. You'll see that the right one has red in it (51, actually), whereas the left one doesn't.

Comment: @animuson: If you'd work for Pixar or nVidia or some of the other graphics related companies, you even have to be perfectionist on this. You would then even be perfectionist on random number generation and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this does have to do with color management but I'm not sure what needs to be turned on where. [Here is one of a few articles](http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html) I found that goes into this that I hope is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is the gamma correction. PNG format has an option to store a gamma correction value, so the image will look the same in monitors with different gamma correction.
The problem is that some browsers use this information an others don't.

The following image has gamma correction on, and will look the same in every browser, but it can give you problems in firefox if you want the image color to match html and css colors:
[image: image with gamma correction]